# Can't connect to windows server with rdesktop - “No valid license available” error

Tags: linux, linux-mint, remote, remote-desktop, rdesktop

Im using Remotedesktop Client 0.23 on Linux Mint. When im trying to connect to a windows server, I get the following error: Disconnect: No valid license available

I know that I'm supposed to delete a file, but I can't find it.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't actually a licensing issue with your Windows Server or Terminal Services setup?

Comment: @derobert: Can it be something wrong with the licensing on the windows server?

What do you mean with Terminal Service setup? It has worked before.

Comment: When I Google for that error message, I get a lot of results saying that its from not having Terminal Services licensing (on the Windows Server) properly configured: accidentally using 120-day temporary licenses, not being in per-connection mode, etc.

Comment: @derobert: So the problem is on the windows server? What is Terminal Services?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows licensing.

Comment: Yes, it's probably one the Windows side. At least I'd start looking there first (e.g., does the Event Log show anything useful?). Terminal Services has apparently be renamed Remote Desktop Services is the newest Windows Server releases, but its the server side.

Comment: I would suggest deleting your question here and asking on Super User. Alternatively, flag your question "other - needs mod attention" and ask for it to be migrated to Super User. But I'd search there first to see if there is already an answer there. (The folks over at Super User know a lot more about Windows than we do.)

Comment: This Q may be on topic since he's using a UNIX client to connect to a a RDP server on Windows. It's along the same lines of using PuTTY to connect from Windows to a Unix system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also take a look at using [`xfreerdp`](http://www.freerdp.com/) as a client instead, we use it with Window's license server and it work fine. Also I found this thread which discusses the problem, titled: [rdesktop 'disconnect: No valid license available](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-849378-view-previous.html?sid=fa4ff47438118e083508146b6275ff14).

There was a tip in that thread to try this as a potential workaround with `rdesktop`.

> this is a workaround 
>   i've just seen that if you know the hostname's owner of a valid MS license (CAL temp license) you can use it this way:
>
> ```
>   $ rdesktop -n 'hostname' serverhostname
> ```